# Django: Transmit GET-param after form-submit

Tags: django

I call my page with http://localhost:63314/user/mieter/?wohnungseinheit=1 as a(GET)-parameter.

I would like to use the transmitted parameter as an assignment for the "wohnungseinheit". After I filled in and sent my "form", the GET-parameter is missing.

How can I assign the "wohnungseinheit"?

```
def mieter(request,id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MieterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            tmp = request.GET.get('wohnungseinheit')
            mieter = form.save()#wohnungseinheit=tmp
            print(tmp) #result: None
            Wohnungseinheit = Wohnungseinheiten.objects.get(id=tmp)
            Wohnungseinheit.mieter.add(mieter)
            return render(request,'Immo/user/mieter.html',{'form':form}) # i think i also could use render_to_response
    else:
        if not str == None and str(id).isdigit():
            #unimportant code here

            if blnAllowedAccess:
                form = MieterForm(request.POST)
                return render(request,'Immo/user/mieter.html',{'form':form})
            else:
                #NOTALLOWEDTOACCESS! TODO
                pass
        else:
            tmp = request.GET.get('wohnungseinheit')
            if tmp is not None:
                form = MieterForm(request.POST or None)
                return render(request,'Immo/user/mieter.html',{'form':form})
            else:
                pass #TODO: 404-error
```

EDIT:

models.py:

```
class MieterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    nameL = forms.CharField(required=True,max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        model=Mieter
        fields = ("nameL",)

class Wohnungseinheiten(models.Model):
    mieter = models.ManyToManyField(Mieter,blank=True,null=True)
```

urls.py:

```
    re_path(r'user/mieter/(?:(?P<id>\w+)/)?$', views.mieter,name="mieter"),
```

user/mieter.html:

```
<form class="form-signin" action="{% url 'mieter' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<input class="form-control"  id="{{ form.nameL.auto_id }}" name="nameL"  value="{{ form.nameL.value }} "type="text">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Where does your form "target" parameter point to? Specific url/path please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was: `<a href="{% url 'mieter' %}?wohnungseinheit=1">`

The param could be dynamically assembled by an "if" or "for".